# What font does Apple use for its "light" text?

Tags: font-identification, apple

Apple often uses what looks like a "light" version of Lucida Grande or Lucida Sans Unicode, as seen here:

[image]

I like the font a lot, but neither Lucida Grande nor Lucida Sans has a light version. Is this simply a proprietary Apple font, or is there some way of obtaining it?

Comment: The best close free option is font - Vegur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're after [Myriad Pro Light 300](https://typekit.com/fonts/myriad-pro)

[image: iPhone 5]

Answer (score 4):

They use Myriad:

[image: Myriad Pro Light]

<del>If you are after a free alternative and you don't mind that it isn't an exact match, you could use [Vegur Light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiQaK.png).</del> *Update: Vegur isn't a good recommendation because it has very poor character support (accented characters will not work at all) and it is of dubious authorship: it may be a rip-off of some other font.  It only seems to appear on "dodgy" font sites.*

Answer (score 3):

It's called Myriad Set, used in varying weights (in this case either Thin or Ultralight). It's a custom variation of Myriad Pro, only available to Apple and its marketing/advertising partners.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, Apple's type is a tweaked version of Myriad Pro. You may notice some variations.

Answer (score 0):

Lucida Grande:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JFbcoxh.png]

It's the light version, even though it says regular in the whatfont extention (because weight can be defined on the main font through CSS) it is the light version with a weight of 300

Comment: That sample is definitely Myriad and not Lucida Grande.  I think your tool has failed to pick up on the specific headline font, and is just reporting what their website uses for body text.  Maybe it's because they are using an image replacement trick?

Answer (score 0):

Apple SD Gothic Neo thin is probably the closest to what they use

[image]

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)

Comment: I think that font is designed for Japanese (eg Japanese iOS users?). I believe the sample is Myriad.

Answer (score -2):

Apple always makes it beautiful.
The latest font they use for 2015, is
San Fransisco.
Just Google it. Apple has designed it's own font.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this isn't actually true anymore. I think Apple currently uses their own font, called San Francisco (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Helvetica was for iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Hey Prateek. Welcome to GD.SE! Your answer is correct in the sense that Apple uses San Francisco NOW, but this question is a couple of years old and was specifically asking about the font used in the picture they showed. If you wanted to include a screenshot of what San Francisco looks like, it might help people who come across your answer 2 years from now. :)